# Android spinner give a NullPointException

Tags: java, android

Any ideas why this code throws a NullPointException?

```
    Spinner spinnerLoadLayouts = (Spinner)this.findViewById(R.id.spnLoadLay);

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = 
    new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, new ArrayList<CharSequence>());

    adapter.add("aaa"); adapter.add("bbb");
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnerLoadLayouts.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Thanks! :)

Comment: where exactly the NullPointerEx is thrown? I assume the last line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that the View or Activity cannot find `R.id.spnLoadLay`

[Quote](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewById%28int%29):

> findViewById: Returns: The View that has the given tag in the hierarchy or null

Comment: yep, sorry, forgot that it comes from a dialogView. :) Thanks, works. now.

Answer (score 1):

If the error is on the last line, then `spinnerLoadLayouts` is NULL.

This could be because you can only do this

```
(Spinner)this.findViewById(R.id.spnLoadLay);
```

If the `spnLoadLay` view is actually in the current view (is available in an XML you have allready called `setContentView` on for instance). If you haven't put that on the screen, you can't find it using `findViewById`. You need to use an `Inflater` for that